# Trust anchor for certification path not found in android

Tags: android, cordova

Hello I am implementing SSL pinning with Cordova following this link https://github.com/Wallethub/cordova-plugin-sslsupport
using the link and setup from android but pinning is not happening with the certificate

Can any one help me how to resolve the issue

I had created assets folder and added certificates is my sub folder under that added my certicate named as googel_cer.cert